# Restricting number of wireless connections on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, usb

I'm trying to configure my office network in such a way that no data can be leaked from the computers connected on the network via the USB ports.

Currently, I've used a straight forward registry hack to disable write access for all the USB ports on the network. Pen drives and hard drives couldn't copy anything from the machine, but the machine could read from them without any problem.

But now, I recently realized that if I attach a USB WiFi or a 3G dongle to the computer it can connect to an external network which will allow access to someone to upload the sensitive data out.

So my question is:

Is there a way to restrict dongles from being recognized on the computer all together? Or can I restrict any new wireless connection to be installed on the computer?

I am also using a netgear wifi dongle to connect to the network which is mac verified on the router and I would not want that to stop working either.

Comment: Worth bearing in mind you'd still have the possibility of people connecting to your network with their coputer via a cable, or with their computer via wireelss since you're only talking of putting a restriction on your computers. I suppose most would look toward putting the restriction at the router level.

Comment: I am planning to install a UTM before the router itself to avoid any loss of data. But to avoid people to abuse the USB ports I need a separate solution.

Comment: So it sounds like you'd be blocking off foreign MACs.  if they plug a USB stick in to make a wireless USB client,  it will have a foreign / its own unique MAC. It will be as if it were some other/new computer trying to connect. Really in a sense it's not the computers connecting, it's the network adaptors within or dangling from the computers.  So any new network adaptor is as  foreign/new, regardless of which computer it is in. You can choose not to accept MACs other than particular ones.

Comment: They would not be able to access my network via a new USB Wifi adapter yes, but they can use it to access any of the other networks around my office.
Also, instead of using a Wifi dongle, one can use a 3G dongle which would give them direct access to the internet anyway to upload any of the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about employees leaking data, you can try setting the users to Standard Users such that they are not Administrators on the computers and may not be able to install drivers needed by the USB wireless devices. However, anyone with physical access to a computer can usually find a way to do what they need to if they are intent on leaking data maliciously. They can reverse your registry hacks or use a wireless Ethernet bridge, for example, to use the Ethernet port to connect to wireless networks. Or they can email files or upload them to cloud services.

Comment: Only one ethernet port would be used for the computer which would be connected via a UTM, which I believe will also be able to restrict access to common FTP sites so cloud services would not be a problem.